# Integrating Chosen JQuery plugin with Symfony2 SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, jquery-chosen

I am using SonataAdminBundle version 2.0 with Symfony2 version 2.0.11

My entities have several OneToMany relationships and I want to make the selection easier by using the [Chosen JQuery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/).

Here is the Entity definition:

```
class Merchant
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="merchants")
     */
    public $categories;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="merchants")
     */
    protected $primaryCategory;

...
}
```

Here is a sample Admin code:

```
$formMapper
        ->add('name')
        ->add('primaryCategory', 'sonata_type_model', array('attr' => array('class' => 'chzn-select')))
        ->add('categories', 'sonata_type_model', array('expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true, 'attr' => array('class' => 'chzn-select')))
```

I have confirmed that chosen.css and chosen.js are loaded in the page. But I don't see the corresponding sprites being loaded. Neither do I see any "Chosen" magic.

Am I missing something here?
How can I correctly integrate Chosen with SonataAdmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked,
I had forgotten to initialize the select options with chosen on $().ready()

Here is the code:

```
 $().ready(function () {
    $('select.chzn-select').chosen();
...
...
```

It comes neatly now.